# Devise 3.11, Rails 4. Get list of signed in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I am in my admin interface I'd like to see what users are signed in.

like this

User name, Signed in ?

Elvis, no

Chet Baker, no

Michael Jackson, no

Herbie Hancock, Yes

Justin Bieber, Yes

Using devise, I added the trackable feature

in my migration

```
t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
```

Problem is that if a user signs out the `:current_sign_in_at` and `:current_sign_in_ip` is not set to nil.

I added this to my sessions_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    current_user.current_sign_in_at = nil
    current_user.save
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(current_user))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Now the `current_sign_in_at` is updated when the users sign out.

Then I added the `:timeoutable` mpdule. When the sessions time out the `current_sign_in_at` not is updated.

After all this hacking, I begin to wounder: Does not devise have a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard.

If the user signs out it is easy to nil out the ':current_sign_in_at'

It's a bit harder when the session times out. When the user tries to enter after the time out devise does a `warden.logout` on the session and the user have to sign in again.
If the user does not do anything or just closes the browser he/she are still signed in, as far as the server knows.

To make this work we'd have to:
A: Ask the clients browser for env['warden'].session.last_request_at all the time 
B: Create the session table with 'rake db:sessions:create' and put this in the session_store.rb initializer.

```
Squadlink::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Then the sessions will be on the server for better control.

For now i did this

config/initializers/warden.rb

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |record, warden, opts|
  if record.respond_to?(:logout_stamp!)
    record.logout_stamp!
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```
def logout_stamp!
  self.current_sign_in_at = nil
  self.current_sign_in_ip = nil
  self.save
end
```

And removed the

```
current_user.current_sign_in_at = nil
current_user.save
```

lines form the sessions_controller destroy action.

If the user signs out or gets signed out the 'current_sign_in_at' and 'current_sign_in_ip' are set to nil.

Hope it helps someone.